# IntelliJ 13 Ultimate Not Enabling PHP

Tags: php, intellij-idea, ide

I have `Intellij 13 Ultimate` IDE running from past couple of years. Today got my system formatted due to some problem. When I re-installed the same version back with the license its not enabling PHP file support.

Screenshot

[image]

Has anybody faced this issue, or anyone can suggest how to fix it? 
Tried searching for the `com.jetbrains.php` but coudln't find anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The PHP plugin is not bundled with IntelliJ IDEA Ultimate; you need to install it from the plugin manager (Settings | Plugins).

Comment: Hi @Yole, Yeah I tried searching it in the Plugin Repository, but didn't find it there.

Comment: It's the first hit when you enter "PHP" as the search string. http://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/6610?pr=idea

Comment: Yeah,  I had tried that earlier there was compatibility issues as I was on a different version of IntelliJ. Anyways thanks, I got the correct version now.